# Is there any way to add CSS/JS files dynamically in Django templates?

Tags: css, django, django-views, django-templates, content-delivery-network

Actually I am trying to implement a content delivery application in Django to support my SASS based application with dynamic style sheets and Javascript files. I searched a lot but wasn't able to find a single solution for this.

In a nutshell, I simply want to implement an application in which views fetch the CSS/JS files and then use the URLs of these views in a Django template (HTML) so that the response of those views as the content of a CSS/js file could include in the Django template.

I would be very grateful if someone helps me with this problem. I am stuck on this and not able to proceed further with my project.

It sucks a lot.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: **https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files** please go through this reference

Comment: @RayeesAC I haven't found this article helpful there isn't defined or explained any way to include dynamic CSS/JS file in Django templates

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html#static-files-setup check this ref too @
IP Flashor Ali

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/django-cdn-integration are want like this.. @IP Flashor Ali

Comment: @RayeesAC this is also not the thing I am asking for kindly read the question again, please